# Proving a property for some general transformation $\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^s \to (0,1)^{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

The author of the prob/stat textbook I am using casually threw out a statement that I've been driving myself crazy trying to prove. It goes like this:

Let $s < k-1$ for some positive integers $s$ and $k$. Consider a subset $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^s$, and let $W = \{ (p_1, \dots, p_k) \; | \; p_i > 0 \; \forall i = 1, \dots, k \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1 \}$. Now let $\mathbf{f}: \Omega \to W$ satisfy the following properties:

1. For $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_s) \in \Omega$, $f_i(\mathbf{x}) > 0 $ for each $i = 1, \dots, k$.
2. $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(\mathbf{x}) = 1$

We are also given that none of the components $x_1, \dots, x_s$ in an element $\mathbf{x} \in \Omega$ can be written as a function of any of the other elements.

The claim is that $s < k-1 \Rightarrow \mathbf{f}(\Omega) \subset  W $, i.e. that $\mathbf{f}$ is not onto.

I am not at all sure how to go about showing this. Initial attempts involved supposing that $\mathbf{f}$ was onto and using the fact that it therefore had a right inverse to show that $k-1 \le s$. Got stuck there. Also got stuck trying to derive a contradiction of the hypothesis that no $x_i$ can be written as function of the other $x_j$.

Since the claim deals with a relation between the dimension of $\Omega$ and $W$, I am vaguely reminded of the rank-nullity theorem, although this would be more general since $\mathbf{f}$ is not necessarily linear.

Taking it a step farther, I thought that the proof might involve the implicit function theorem / rank theorem, which you might be able to apply if you assume that $\mathbf{f}$ is a continuously differentiable function. But after that, I'm stuck. Can I get a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need some other assumptions.

Take $k=3$ and $\Omega = (0,\frac 12)\cup(\frac 12,1)$ then $W$ is an equilateral triangle and there exists a surjection $f:\Omega\to W$ called a [Peano Curve.](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Peano_curve)

(Notice I've had to remove three points from the interval $[0,1]$ corresponding to the corners of the triangle.)

Check in the book to see if the author has made some other assumption you've missed.

I can't find an example of the exact curve I'm thinking of, and it's hard to describe without drawing a picture. but there exists a continuous map $f$ (it's a Peano curve, but slightly different to the link) from $[0,1]$ to the equilateral triangle that's measure preserving.  That is if  $X\in[0,1]$ is uniformly distributed, then $f(X)$ is uniformly distributed in the triangle.

So from a probability point of view there's a very important way that the statement isn't true.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for getting back to me. Took a while for the geometry to click in my head, but your counterexample makes sense now. One point of confusion is -- were you able to remove 0, $\frac{1}{2}$, and 1 from [0,1] arbitrarily to get the curve to work out? Also, since the Peano curve is not injective, isn't there a possibility that you would have to remove multiple points from [0,1] so that nothing maps to the corners of the triangle? Am I just missing something in how the curve is defined?

Comment: As for additional assumptions, the author doesn't explicitly state any, but the examples given all have injective transformations $\mathbf{f}$. If we add that assumption, I wonder if the statement becomes true...

Comment: The $\frac 12$ is true for the particular curve I linked to, for the other curve I was thinking about I would have to remove $\frac 23$.  It happens to be true for both curves that only one point maps to each corner.  It doesn't matter anyway, because there's no assumption on $\Omega$ so I can set $\Omega$ to be the set of points $\left\{x\in (0,\frac 12)\cup(\frac 12,1):\nexists y<x \text{s.t.} f(x)= f(y)\right\}$. And $f:\Omega\to W$ is bijective.  It might just be a mistake in the book, these things happen sometimes.

Comment: True -- my curiosity always gets the better of me and I feel like I need to investigate every little detail so I tend to comb my books pretty thoroughly. It is always frustrating to run into a mistake like this though -- what if I had just accepted it and moved on? I would believe (maybe not remember though) something false :( Anyway, thanks for all your help!